# Use lodash to apply a function to filtered properties of an object

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'd like to use `lodash` to selectively mutate properties in an object.

```
var foo = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };

function addOne(num) {
    return num + 1;
}

var propsToTransform = ['a', 'b'];

_(foo).pick(propsToTransfrom)
  .map(addOne);

// I want foo = { 'a': 2, 'b':3, 'c':3 }
```

Is it possible to achieve this using the kind of composition I've outlined above or should I stick to something like

```
_.forEach(propsToTransform, (prop) => {
  if (foo[prop]) {
    foo[prop] = addOne(foo[prop]);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`_.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) and [`_.protoype.value`](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-value) as andlrc pointed out. You'll end up creating a new object with the new values and merge it with the original one :

```
var foo = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 };
var propsToTransfrom = ['a', 'b']

// Create a new object with the new, modified values and merge it onto the original one
var bar = _.merge(foo, _(foo).pick(propsToTransfrom).mapValues(addOne).value());

console.log(bar); // { 'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3 }

function addOne(num) {
    return num + 1;
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution. You can be a bit more aggressive and do away with `bar`. It shortens to `_.merge(foo, _(foo).pick .... );` since `merge` will mutate `foo`.

@dmlittle if you can set the output of `console.log` to `{ 'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3 }` I can mark as accepted.